# week highlight is not working properly on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar in my project. Please look at the following fiddle,

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ohxvz2o/3/)

1) The first column is week and remaining columns are days.

2) In week columns I displayed some random numbers. Don't consider days.

3) When I mouseover on that week numbers, it will highlight that week friday to next thursday(total 7 days).

My expectation is :

1) When I mouse over on week "td" it will show one tooltip.

2) Please check the fiddle, If I mouseleave on week random number, it is not highlighting friday to thursday.

3) My requirement, when I mouse over on random numbers and particular "td", it should highlight friday to thursday. When I mouse leave on that "td" then only i need to hide that highlight.

```js
var weekRandom;
 var dayRandom;
 
  var eventsArray = [ 
  ];

  var dayNames = [ 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
    'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    {
     editable : true,
     weekNumbers : true,
     allDaySlot : true,
     weekNumberTitle : 'week',
     eventLimit : true, // allow "more" link when too many events
     selectable : true,
     dayNamesShort : dayNames,
     eventLimit : 1,
     events : eventsArray,
     cc_monthPrev : 0,
     cc_monthNext : 2,

     columnFormat : {
      month : 'dddd', // Monday, Wednesday, etc
      week : 'dddd, MMM dS', // Monday 9/7
      day : 'dddd, MMM dS' // Monday 9/7
     },

     eventRender : function(event, element) {

      var html = "<div style='float:right'>" + 'welcome'
        + "</div>" + "</div>";
      element.append(html);
     }

    });

  $("td.fc-day.fc-widget-content")
    .each(
      function(index) {
       var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
       dayRandom = $(this)
         .append(
           "</br><span style='font-size: 30px;font-weight: 600;color: green;'>"
             + random
             + "%</span></br><span>99,998</span><span>/</span><span style='font-weight:100'>99,999</span>");
      });
  $("td.fc-week-number.fc-widget-content").prepend(
    "<span class='weekFormat' style='float:left'>WK</span>");

  
  $("td.fc-week-number.fc-widget-content")
  .each(
    function(index) {
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
     weekRandom = $(this)
       .append(
         "<span class='weekNo' style='font-size: 20px;font-weight: 600;color: orange;'>"
           + random
           + "%</span>");
     
   });
  
  
  $("td.fc-week-number.fc-widget-content").find('.weekNo').each(function(){
   $(this).on('mouseover',function(){
    var weekNo = $(this).text();
    var weekNoCustm = weekNo.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    console.log('weekNoCustm------'+weekNoCustm);
    if(weekNoCustm>0){
     $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').siblings('.fc-fri').addClass('weekHilt');
     $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').siblings('.fc-sat').addClass('weekHilt');
     $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-mon').addClass('weekHilt');
     $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-tue').addClass('weekHilt');
     $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-wed').addClass('weekHilt');
     $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-thu').addClass('weekHilt');
     $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-sun').addClass('weekHilt'); 
     
    }
   })
   $(this).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').siblings('.fc-fri').removeClass('weekHilt');
    $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').siblings('.fc-sat').removeClass('weekHilt');
    $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-mon').removeClass('weekHilt');
    $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-tue').removeClass('weekHilt');
    $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-wed').removeClass('weekHilt');
    $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-thu').removeClass('weekHilt');
    $(this).parent('.fc-week-number ').closest('.fc-week').next('tr').find('.fc-sun').removeClass('weekHilt');
   })
  });
  
   
  
  
      
  $(".fc-toolbar").css("display", "none");

  $(".fc-widget-content")
    .on(
      'mouseover',
      function() {

       $('#cal-info').addClass('hide');
       var data = $(this).html();
       var offset = $(this).offset();
       $('#cal-info').css('left', offset.left);
       $('#cal-info').css('top', (offset.top - 40));
       $('#cal-info')
         .html(
           '<span class="zoomBy">Zoom By:</span>'
             + '</br></br>'
             + '<a href="dayResort.html" id="utilizationResortId" target="_blank">Resort</a>'
             + '</br>'
             + '<a href="dayResort.html" id="utilizationBrandId" target="_blank">Brand</a>'
             + '</br>'
             + '<a href="dayResort.html" id="utilizationRepoId" target="_blank">Repository</a>'
             + '</br>'
             + '<a href="dayResort.html" id="utilizationConsumerId" target="_blank">Consumer Type</a>');

       //p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
       $('#cal-info').removeClass('hide');
      });
  $(".fc-week-number").on('mouseover', function() {

   //$('#cal-info').addClass('hide');
  });
  $(".row").on('mouseleave', function() {

   $('#cal-info').addClass('hide');

  });
```

```css
body {
 margin-top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
.tag{
  background-color:grey;
  color:#fff;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-top:8px !important;
  padding:3px;
  max-height:90px;
  overflow: visible;  
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
}
.tag:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 16px solid red;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}

#calendar {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.weekHilt{
 background: #1c90f3 !important;
}
```

```html
Start Date :<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value=""> 
End date :<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value=""></br></br></br></br>

<div id='calendar'></div>
<div class="tag hide" id="cal-info">
```

Please help me how can I do this..

Answer (score 0):

Might this solves your problem

```
$("#calendar").on("mouseover", "tr.fc-week", function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
$("#calendar").on("mouseout", "tr.fc-week", function() {
  $("#calendar tr.fc-week").removeClass("active");
});
```

And add this CSS:

```
tr.active > td:not(:first-child) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ohxvz2o/1/

Comment: Sorry. Its not working. When I mouseover on tooltip div, that time also it should highlight that week's friday to next saturday. Already its highlighting. When I mouseover on tooltip its not highlighting.

Comment: Please now look at my fiddle on top.